# Show that $m(A)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Let $​0< \delta <1$. Let ​$ A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a lebesgue measurable set. Suppose that for any interval $(a, b)$ we have

$$m(A \cap(a,b) )\leq \delta \cdot m(a,b).$$

Here $m$ denotes the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$​. Show that $ m(A)=0$.

COULD YOU PLEASE HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far.

Comment: [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem)

Comment: Please correct the first sentence in the second paragraph.

Comment: This sounds a little bit like you want us to solve a homework problem...

Comment: It is not homework. I will have a qualifying exam soon and I have seen this problem somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: It suffices to treat the case $m(A)<\infty.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$  Then there exist open intervals $I_n$ that cover $A$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(I_n) < m(A) + \epsilon.$ We then have

$$m(A) = m(A\cap(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(A\cap I_n) \le \delta \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m( I_n).$$